# Probability of satisfying a bound

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose for sequences $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$, $i=1,\dots,K$ the following condition holds:
\begin{equation*}
Prob\{a_i\leq b_i\leq \gamma\}\geq\beta,\quad\forall i.
\end{equation*}

Then does the following hold?

\begin{equation}
Prob\left\{\max_{i=1,\dots,K} a_i\leq \max_{i=1,\dots,K} b_i\leq\gamma\right\}\geq \beta,
\end{equation}

where $\gamma$ is a constant.

Comment: I think you should replace $\max$ for a $\sup$ (supremum).

Comment: Which quantities are random variables and which are not?

Comment: Are the $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$ independent of each other? Integrable? Uniformly integrable? Are there any assumptions on the sequences that you have left out?

Comment: Edited the question. Actually $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$ are not random variables.

Comment: If the sequences are not random variables, and if $\gamma$ is not a random variable, then there is no source of randomness, and the "probability" does not make sense.

Comment: Then what if $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$, $i=1,\dots,K$  are independent random variables?

Answer (score 1):

The second inequality does not necessarily follow from the first. Let $\ a_1,a_2,\dots, a_K, b_1,b_2,\dots,b_K\ $ be independent random variables, all distributed uniformly over the interval $\ [0,2]\ $. Then $\ Prob\left\{a_i\le b_i\le1\right\}=\frac{1}{8}\ $ for all $\ i\ $.  But $\ A=\max_\limits{1\le i\le K}a_i\ $ and $\ B=\max_\limits{1\le i\le K}b_i\ $ are independent random variables with distribution $\ Prob\left\{A\le x\right\}= Prob\left\{
B\le x\right\}=\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^K\ $ for $\ 0\le x\le 2\ $. Therefore
\begin{align}
Prob\left\{A\le
B\le 1\right\}&=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{b}{2}\right)^K\frac{Kb^{K-1}}{2^K}db\\
&= \frac{1}{2\cdot4^K}\\
&\not\ge\frac{1}{8}\ \text{ for any } K\ge 2\ .
\end{align}